# Change upload directory jQuery File Upload

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload

I am using the jQuery-File-Upoad plugin on a php-website that is available at  https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload .
The files are by default uploaded in the php/files/ folder that can be found in the folder where the plugin is installed.

I would like to be able to change the directory onto which the files are uploaded.  An ideas how to accomplish this?

Comment: Please write code what have you tried.

Comment: I  haven't tried anything because I don't know where to start...

Answer (score -1):

Please try changing value of URL and if possible provide your code here

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
        // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
        //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
        url: 'server/php/'
    });
```

Comment: I changed the 'upload_dir' and 'upload_url' in UploadHandler.php to the folder I envisage and that works. I had to hardcode that folder like for instance: 
'upload_url'=>'http://www.karinedaelman.be/Test/images/large/'

But I would like to do this dynamically, by passing a parameter... I don't know how and where to do that... How can I pass a parameter to the UploadHandler class in UploadHandler.php ??